# I am getting type mismatch error in Spark SQL 2.x - 'Expected col but found array of column '

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter out 2 columns from a dataframe columns list and give it as argument to a hash function. 
Using Spark Scala 2.11.8
Spark SQL - 2.3.1

I am trying to generate hash value for required columns (customerId,address).

It can be achieved by mentioning the column names in function

```
 //existingdataDF.withColumn("hashkey",hash(col("customerId"),col("address") )).show
```

but what if we have 100 columns and I need to include 98 columns except the 2 columns.

So I need to filter the unwanted columns and generate hash value for all the columns. (Need hash value to implement SCD 2 on the data)

```
case class Customer(customerId: Int, address: String, current: Boolean, effectiveDate: Date, endDate: Date)
 import spark.implicits._
    val existingdataDF = Seq(
      Customer(1, "old address for 1", false, null, "2018-02-01"),
      Customer(1, "current address for 1", true, "2018-02-01", null),
      Customer(2, "current address for 2", true, "2018-02-01", null),
      Customer(3, "current address for 3", true, "2018-02-01", null)
    ).toDF()
          val  existingDFhashcolumns =existingdataDF.filter(x=> x!=col("effectiveDate") && x!=col("endDate"))
val hashcolumns =existingDFhashcolumns.columns.map(col(_))
existingdataDF.withColumn("hashkey",hash(hashcolumns)).show
```

Comment: Please add complete steps, what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Dhakad   I have added more info to question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get list of required hascolumns, then apply the hash.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val hashcolumns =existingdataDF.filter(x=> x!=col("effectiveDate") && x!=col("endDate")).columns.map(col(_))
existingdataDF.withColumn("hashkey",hash(hashcolumns:_*)).show
```